# RestSharp code generated form Postman does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, restsharp, postman

I am testing the QuickPay API in Postman and everything works fine. When I use the Postman Code Generator to generate a RestSharp snippet of the succesful result, the code does not return a status 200 against the API, and nothing happens.

I have posted the generated code her (altered the auth code though)

```
var client = new RestClient("http://api.quickpay.net/subscriptions/18612/recurring?Accept-Version=v10&id=18427612&amount=9900&order_id=test1234");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("postman-token", "145e85d9-0e36-4e6a-2742-b36fb3dccadb");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("accept-version", "v10");
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic OjczYWY3NzlmZDYzMjIxNGUx33yYj5266ZkO222Z322221M34334433434344ZWY=");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Any help is very much appreciated.
Best regards

Comment: thank you for pointing out the Postman Code Generator :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that instead of posting parameters into the url as querystring parameters, I should post them as parameters into the reqeuest method. No need for the Postman token nor the cache-control headers. And importantly, the url should be https://api.quickpay.net/subscriptions/18612/recurring